# Excel VBA Macro or something else?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a SpreadSheet I am trying to figure out. I am not sure if code is the best way to go or not but i couldnt get it dont with a pivot table, So i coded a macro instead.

Below is my spreadSheet

```
(Cooks can be waiters)
Sheet1
CooksName | Waiter | DishServed
Bob, Joe, Fish
Joe, Bob, Chicken
Amy, Dan, Beef
Amy, Dan, Beef


**This is just a list i keep in sheet two for a picklist in Sheet1
Sheet2
Staff|Inventory
Bob, Fish
Joe, Chicken
Amy, Beef
Dan
```

This is what I want sheet3 to look like

```
Sheet3
Staff, Fish, Chicken, Beef
Joe, 1, 1, 0
Bob, 1, 1, 0
Amy, 0, 0, 2
Dan, 0, 0,2
```

I prob made this to complex but I tried to create a macro to handle this.

```
Public Sub test()

Dim rng1Sheet3 As Range
Dim rng2Sheet1 As Range
Dim rngName As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Integer
 x = 20

 'Loop through Sheet3 Column A - 20 - This assignment comes from sheet 2
For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count - 20).End(xlUp).Row

'Set The value for the static list produced in Sheet 2
    Set rng1Sheet3 = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & i)
    'Get Car Type

    For j = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Set the value for each for Comparision
        Set rng2Sheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j)

        If rng2Sheet1.Value = rng1Sheet3.Value Then



            End If

           ' rng2Sheet1.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E" & x)

        End If

    Set rng2 = Nothing
Next j

Set rng1 = Nothing

 Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking if there is a better way to do this without using VBA ?

Comment: I am stuck on the VBA Aspect. If you look at the code I can find the name in each sheet but how can I Add the number to sheet 3 inventory next to the staff name

Comment: Also if there is a better way I would like to know. Couldnt figure this out using pivot table

Comment: Are values in `sheet3` detemined by `sheet1` only?

Comment: What is `Sheet1` (Cooks can be waiters)?

Comment: Yes sheet3 is determined by sheet1

Comment: Sheet1 (cooks can be waiters) meaning when calculating sheet3 column a checks both cooks and waiters. That's all

Comment: Any help is appreciated researched this for to long